# Lossy to lossless conversion (audio)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3, flac

I have an mp3 file which i want to convert to a flac. I realise that it wont "improve" the quality rather I want it in a flac format so that when I edit it each time and re encode it, it won't degrade in quality.

The questions

1 If i convert it to flac will I degrade the mp3 file in doing so atleast 1 time?

2 Does changing the container ie mp3 to flac without encoding or changing the bit rate and frequency actually degrade the audio? If not how can I accomplish this?

3 Is there a better way for me to deal with my situation?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to WAV, 24-bit, keep the sample rate the same. I don't know any audio editor that can work directly with FLAC.
You've already lost data due to the original lossy compression. You don't lose any more converting it to WAV. You can't just 'change the container'. It just doesn't work like that.

Once inside a DAW, any editing will be done at 32- or 64-bit float, best preserving the audio content.

Each export then is 'one more lossy save' from the same quality source, assuming you're exporting back to mp3/aac etc. That's the best you can get.

Comment: AFAIK, Audacity can read FLAC (maybe it requires the ffmpeg library installed, but not a big deal).

Comment: I use audacity for editing. I know data has been lost since its in mp3 but changing it to WAV wont lead to any more losses correct provided sample rate same? and wont changing the bit rate to 24 bit degrade the mp3?

Comment: also if i export it form a wav to wav will it still result in losses after editing ?

Comment: WAV doesn't have a "bit rate" like lossy audio, it has a sample rate & bit *depth*. They are not related in the same way. Audacity actually states it can import & export FLAC. It doesn't say it can use it as-is. Empirically, a FLAC imported to Audacity then saved in a project has the file size of a 32-bit float WAV [as mentioned in my answer.]

Comment: thank you for your response  helped massively

Comment: @JohnStrauss15 To be accurate, `WAV` is a container, not a stream format. It can contain various audio streams, including mp3 streams. If you want an uncompressed audio stream in a WAV container, it can be a PCM stream, but it's better to explicitly request it in the conversion: in ffmpeg this is for instance `-c:a pcm_s24le` ("s24" for "signed 24 bits integers" and "le" for "little endian"). Check [this page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types). Reading then writing PCM streams doesn't result in any loss.

Comment: @JohnStrauss15 Regarding the bit depth, the effective bit depth of a mp3 stream is less than 16 bits anyway, so casting it to 24 bits is completely safe in terms of retaining the useful information.

Comment: @Tetsujin *"Audacity actually states it can import & export FLAC. It doesn't say it can use it as-is."*: Audacity has its own internal representation of the audio tracks, which are not stored as WAV either. It doesn't use any file -WAV included- "as-is", and the procedure to read an input file or write an output file is the same whatever the file type (and writing a WAV file is also in the export menu). Using FLAC to store the input and output files makes perfect sense if one wants to save ~50% disk space, and this is as lossless as using a WAV/PCM file.

Comment: tbh, I never use Audacity unless someone else mentions it ;) As far as I can see, it stores, in whatever actual format, something the equivalent size of 32-bit float, so you may as well feed it 32-bit float in the first place, then throw out your original if you need to save space. Personally I just avoid flac, as nothing I run uses it natively, everything wants to convert it to something more useful at import.

Comment: How Audacity stores the samples internally (16 or 24 bits integers, or 32 bits floats) is a user choice. What I meant is that whatever the editing tool, reading/writing files implies a conversion, whatever the file. The conversion can be straightforward in case of the WAV/PCM files, still this is a conversion (even a WAV file is not necessarily made of a contiguous sample stream, there can be interleaved metadata).

Comment: @PierU - you're just making this all far more complicated than it needs to be. No-one really cares what's going on inside the file structure, so long as they can use it in whatever editor they happen to choose. Anything else is for software engineers, not audio engineers.

Comment: On the contrary I am making things simple for the end-user: for editing purpose you can use any lossless format of your choice, compressed or uncompressed. You don't mind about disk space? Then WAV/PCM is fine. You don't mind about the time spent to compress/uncompress the stream? Then FLAC (or ALAC) is fine. The way this is handled internally is not your business and this should not influence your choice.

Comment: @PierU - tell you what - rather than going on & on in comments… why don't you write your own answer, then people can vote on it.

Comment: As you like, although I don't see it as a competition...

Answer (score 0):

1. No: the original source of the MP3 file was very likely a 16 bits one (such as a CD), so converting to a 16 bits FLAC with the same sample rate will retain all the original information. Even if the source had a larger bit depth (e.g. 24 bits), the effective bit depth of a mp3 stream (i.e. with a S/N ratio above 1) is far less than 16 bits anyway, so a 16 bits FLAC always do... That said, if your editing software can read the MP3 format, there's no need to convert the input file to FLAC at this point.
2. *"changing the container ie mp3 to flac without encoding"* is not possible. A FLAC file can contain only a flac stream (and creating a flac stream is already (lossless) "encoding")
3. Better: no; different: possibly.

### Editing workflow

[input file]-->Editing-->[intermediate file]-->Editing-->[intermediate file]-->Editing-->[output file]

Input file: as I wrote, if your input file in a MP3 one, and if your editing sofware can read MP3 files, there's no need to convert the file to something else. What is important is the chosen bit depth for the importation in the editing sofware.

Editing: since any editing step can potentially introduce noise because of the numerical round-offs, it is important to choose a bit depth larger than 16 bits: it can be 24 bits integers, or 32 bits floats.

Intermediate files: for the very same reason a lossless (compressed or uncompressed) format with 24 or 32 bits should be chosen. Since Audacity can read/write a wide range of file formats, FLAC is a valid option. Another option is the WAV format, embedding a PCM stream. A pcm stream just consists in the uncompressed audio samples. When creating it you have to specify the sample format (16 or 24 bits integer, or 32 bits float). In ffmpeg for instance this is: `-c:a pcm_s24le` (signed 24 bits integer, little endian). FLAC can not handle 32 bits floats (but 24 bits is more than enough in practice).

- Advantage of FLAC: ~50% disk space saving on average
- Advantage of WAV/pcm: faster read/write

Output file: same criteria than for the intermediate files, as you don't know if you will edit it again or not in the future.